# consult tablespace of a table but unused dba_tablespaces

Tags: database, oracle

I need know the tablespace of particulary table, the typical query `SELECT owner, table_name, tablespace_name FROM dba_tables;`  can't use, because I haven't permissions. There is other way to consult Tablespace unused dba_tablespaces?

Answer (score 1):

What permissions do you have?

If you have the ability to query the table in question, for example, you can use `all_tables` which has the same columns that `dba_tables` does but only has data for tables that you have privileges on.

If you don't have privileges on the table are there other data dictionary tables that you do have access to (`dba_segments`, for example)?

If you don't have privileges on the table and you don't have privileges on any of the `dba` data dictionary views, why do you need to know the tablespace?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`USER_TABLES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5489.htm#sthref3126) if the table is in your working schema; and [`ALL_TABLES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2117.htm#i1592091) if you have permissions on the table but it is not in your working schema.

Otherwise change schema or get permission to access `DBA_TABLES`.